# How to get highlighted text in a jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, swing-highlighter

I have a jtextarea with some texts. I use java highligher to highlight some texts on that jtextarea. I want to print the content of that textarea to another textarea with the highlighted texts. Is that possible?
Or is there any way of getting only the highlighted text inside a jtextarea?

Comment: Highlighted = selected?  Or do you mean something else

Comment: no, highlight is like check syntax http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.html

Answer (score 3):

You can just ask the text area for the selected text using the [`getSelectedText`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectedText%28%29) method.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [getHighlights()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.html#getHighlights%28%29) method of your Highlighter.  From there, you can retrieve the offsets of the start and end of highlighting.