# Using JEditorPane to open a text file

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, input

I am trying to open a text file in a frame using JEditorPane (in an non-editable mode). However, I believe I am having problems with setting up my input stream and output stream. Kindly, look at my code and tell where I am doing wrong.

---

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class TextEditor extends JFrame{

private JEditorPane editorpane;
JScrollPane editorScrollPane;
String filename="D:\\abc.txt";
Reader filereader;

public TextEditor()
{       
        editorpane= new JEditorPane();
        editorpane.setEditable(false);

        if (filename != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                filereader=new FileReader(filename);
                editorpane.setPage(filename);
            }

            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Attempted to read a bad file " + filename);
            }
         }

        else
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file");
        }

        //Put the editor pane in a scroll pane.
        editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorpane);
            editorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        editorScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 145));
        editorScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    TextEditor obj= new TextEditor();
    obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    obj.setSize(600,600);
    obj.setLocation(100,100);
    obj.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: you should rather print the message of the IOException. This will give you a true hint on what is going on: Access denied? File not found? Disk error?

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Now the error message is : java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\abc.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: Try "file:///D:/abc.txt"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening a text file in a frame using swing components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477579/opening-a-text-file-in-a-frame-using-swing-components)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the argument as a `URL` for `JEditorPane.setPage`, you could use:

```
File file = new File(filename);
editorpane.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
```

Also don't forget to add your `JEditorPane` to the frame so that it can be seen:

```
add(editorScrollPane);
```

To view the disk error you're getting add:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

to the `IOException` block.

Comment: Still the same error : Attempted to read a bad file file:\D:\abc.txt

Comment: Yes, the file exists. I am able to open the file by
 doing this on the command prompt : D:\>abc.txt

Comment: Now after so much of your help, error messages are gone. But still my frame does not open the file. Simply a blank frame appears.

Answer (score 2):

```
editorpane.getEditorKit().read(filereader, editorpane.getDocument(), 0);
```

Comment: Still the same error : Attempted to read a bad file file:\D:\abc.txt

Answer (score 1):

JEditorPane.setPage() expects an URL, including the protocol: try "file:///D:/abc.txt". The following code should work:

```
String filename="file:///D:/abc.txt";

public TextEditor()
{
        editorpane= new JEditorPane();
        editorpane.setEditable(false);

        if (filename != null)
        {
            try
            {
                editorpane.setPage(filename);
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Attempted to read a bad file " + filename );
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }

        else
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file");
        }

        //Put the editor pane in a scroll pane.
        editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorpane);
            editorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        editorScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 145));
        editorScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
      getContentPane().add(editorScrollPane);

}
```

Comment: Even on doing as you said, still there is the same error message : Attempted to read a bad file file:\D:\abc.txt

Comment: You also need to remove the creation of the FileReader() - you do not use it anyway, and it will throw an IOError since it expects a pure filename, not an URL

Comment: Finally, you also need to add `getContentPane().add(editorScrollPane);` at the end of the TextEditor constructor, otherwise you will not see anything...