# Highlighting few of the words of a text file opened in a frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jeditorpane

I am opening a file in a frame and I wish to highlight few of the words.As I understand,I need to traverse the content of the file. How do I traverse through the contents and what is the related property that I may use for the purpose of highlighting?

---

**UPDATE : MY CODE GOES SOMETHING LIKE THIS**

---

```
private JEditorPane editorpane;
JScrollPane editorScrollPane;

public TextEditor()
{
    editorpane = new JEditorPane();
    editorpane.setEditable(false);

    if (filename != null)
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File(filename);
            editorpane.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Attempted to read a bad file ...");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.println("File name is wrong");
    }

    add(editorpane);
}
```

Comment: Did any of the answers on this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477579/opening-a-text-file-in-a-frame-using-swing-components If so, please accept one. How exactly are you opening a file in a frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To highlight on a `JEditorPane` have a look at this example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class Test {

    // An instance of the subclass of the default highlight painter
    static MyHighlightPainter myHighlightPainter = new MyHighlightPainter(Color.red);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
                jep.setText("Hello to the public");
                frame.add(jep);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

                highlight(jep, "public");//'public is the word to highligh'

            }
        });
    }

    // Creates highlights around all occurrences of pattern in textComp
    public static void highlight(JTextComponent textComp, String pattern) {
        // First remove all old highlights
        removeHighlights(textComp);

        try {
            Highlighter hilite = textComp.getHighlighter();
            Document doc = textComp.getDocument();
            String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
            int pos = 0;

            // Search for pattern
            while ((pos = text.indexOf(pattern, pos)) >= 0) {
                // Create highlighter using private painter and apply around pattern
                hilite.addHighlight(pos, pos + pattern.length(), myHighlightPainter);
                pos += pattern.length();
            }
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        }
    }

    // Removes only our private highlights
    public static void removeHighlights(JTextComponent textComp) {
        Highlighter hilite = textComp.getHighlighter();
        Highlighter.Highlight[] hilites = hilite.getHighlights();

        for (int i = 0; i < hilites.length; i++) {
            if (hilites[i].getPainter() instanceof MyHighlightPainter) {
                hilite.removeHighlight(hilites[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyHighlightPainter extends DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter {

    public MyHighlightPainter(Color color) {
        super(color);
    }
}
```