# Code completion and Syntax Highlighting in Swing

Tags: java, javascript, swing, syntax-highlighting, code-completion

I have started a project that requires syntax highlighting and code completion (a window pops up at the caret location providing suggestions) and can't find a suitable solution. There are multiple Swing components which take text input e.g. JTextArea, JTextPane and JEditorPane which makes it significantly more difficult to figure out which is the correct one to use.

The project is a programmer specific text editor which will have integration with the unity game engine. This meaning code completion and highlighting will be done on JavaScript and C# syntax.

It might be obvious but the general idea is that when the user types, certain words change to a specified colour, these words would be stored in a text file. For the code completion I need to be able to grab the currently typed letters, this detection process will restart by using the space character as the delimiter.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: *"Thanks for your time :)"*  Do you have a question?  If so, what is it?  BTW - `JTextArea` is for plain text so will be unsuited to this task, whereas `JTextPane` and `JEditorPane` support styled text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219625/how-would-be-implements-autosugesion-in-jtextarea-swing/15220056#15220056) which shows *auto completion* for `JTextComponent`, it can show *pop up window* of *auto completion words* to the current caret index on `JTextPane`/`JEditorPane` (+1 @AndrewThompson for the idea):

For `JTextField`:

[image: Using JTextField as AutoSugesstor]

and for other `JTextComponent`s i.e `JTextPane`, `JEditorPane` etc its shown at the current caret index:

[image]

To change text colour of words (i.e syntax highlight) have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13076649/1133011):

[image]

Or if you want rather a highlighted word.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12482171/1133011):

[image]

Comment: The first link was perfect, thank you. All though many things need to be changed it directly solved my problem. I have been trying to figure this one out for a while.

Answer (score 2):

you can look at components from [jintilla](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jintilla/) (a JNI wrapper around the widely used [scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEImage.html)) or [jedit](http://jedit.sourceforge.net/) if their licensing terms fit your use case.