# How highlighter of Java Swing works on marginal cases?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, swing-highlighter

I have this code :

```
JTextArea textComp;

Highlighter hilite = textComp.getHighlighter();

if (word.toString().equals(pattern[i])) 
{
    hilite.addHighlight(posStart, (posEnd), myHighlighter);
    break;
}
```

`word` is a `StringBuilder`

Suppose the condition in `if` matches and `hilite.addHighlight(posStart, (posEnd), myHighlighter);` - this statement is going to execute.
Then the `textComp` contains

> int myVar

And I try to  highlight like this

> **int** myVar

At that time, `posStart = 0` and `posEnd = 3`. But As I am entering something into the `textArea` the highlighter is extending itself to the end like this:

> **int myVar**

Can anyone help me with this?

And if I make the statement:

```
hilite.addHighlight(posStart, (posEnd-1), myHighlighter);
```

Then with `posStart=0, posEnd=3`, then only

> **in**t myVar
>   this happens. i.e "in" is highlighted but "t" is not!

**EDIT**
The function:

```
Highlighter.HighlightPainter myHighlighter = new MyHighlightPainter(
                    Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

            try {
                Highlighter hilite = textComp.getHighlighter();
                Document doc = textComp.getDocument();
                String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
                String[] words = text.split(" ");

                                int posEnd, posStart = 0;
                while (text.length() > posStart) {
                    posEnd = posStart;
                    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
                    while (posEnd < text.length() && text.charAt(posEnd) != ' ') {
                        word.append(text.charAt(posEnd++));
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {

                        if (word.toString().equals(pattern[i])) {
                            hilite.addHighlight(posStart, (posEnd-1), myHighlighter);
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    posStart = posStart + posEnd + 1;
                }
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I have 165lines of code. Can I give it? I can point out the concerned area. Although I have mentioned the same here also. @AndrewThompson

Comment: Could that be of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229611/code-completion-and-syntax-highlighting-in-swing The first answer might solve what you want.

Comment: *"I have 165lines of code. Can I give it?"*  I think 165 LOC counts as 'short'.  As long as it demonstrates the problem, that would make it an SSCCE.

Comment: Okay, I guess it's a little big! But I'll share relevant code.
@SteliosAdamantidis, I tried it, but somehow, it isn't happening!!

Comment: @soham.m17 before anything to read Oracles tutorial about `JTextComponen`t, where is described about `how to search in JTextComponents`, use `JTextPane` for multihighlight & multicoloring, is easier, than by using `JTextArea`, `HighLighter` are stored in array, then have to loop into `HighLighter[]`, have to play with `if - instanceof myHighLighter - then whatever`, only

Comment: @mKorbel thanks, actually I was wondering how this Highlighter works!
I am instructing it to highlight from `0` to `2` index. But it's highlighting only `2` characters i.e `in`t although `0` to `2` is `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this to solve the problem:

```
int wordEnd = 0, wordStart = 0;




Highlighter hilite = textComp.getHighlighter();
                        Document doc = textComp.getDocument();
                        String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());

                        while (text.length() > wordEnd) 
                        {
                            String word = new String();
                            if(text.charAt(wordEnd) == ' ')
                            {
                                word = text.substring(wordStart, wordEnd);
                                for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) 
                                {
                                        if (word.toString().equals(pattern[i])) 
                                        {
                                            hilite.addHighlight(wordStart, (wordEnd), myHighlighter);

                                            break;
                                        }
                                }
                                wordStart = wordEnd + 1;
                            }
                            wordEnd++;
                        }
```

What I did, is to getting a word by detecting a space after it(you can extend the logic) and then highlighting the previous word. This is continuous all through typing.

Comment: Yes, this is what I told you to do in my answer. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

> actually I was wondering how this Highlighter works!

Yes the API is confusing. I believe the first index is meant to be inclusive and the last index exclusive.

Whenever I highlight when searching for a word I use code like:

```
String text = "one two three four...";
String search "three";

int offset = text.indexOf(search);

if (offset != -1)
    textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + search.length(), painter);
```

Comment: And if you delete backwards till "three" and then again type something, the highlighter extends itself. Like if you make the text "one two threeFive" by typing in the `JTextArea` or something like that, then `threeFive` is highlighted.

Comment: Yes, that also is the default behaviour.

Comment: Well, So I've achieved my goal in another way. I'll post that here!!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to not really be how the highlighter highlights text, but rather how the highlight changes as the text is edited. You can deal with this by adding a change listener to the `TextArea`, and adjusting the affected highlights (using `changeHighlight()`) as needed.

Comment: Okay. But I am adding the highlight only. Not changing it. then?