# Highlight a string according to given line number in JtextArea

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextarea, swing-highlighter

Is there any function I can use to actually pass a line number and the string to highlight the word in that line number. I got no clue on how to achieve this.

Am able to load my File on the JtextArea.

The File am loading "Hello.txt" contains:

```
Hello, This
is my first
lesson in Java
Hope You Have a nice 
Time.
```

I want the function to highlight string "first" in line 1.

My Codes:

```
import javax.swing.*;  

import java.util.*;  

import java.io.*;  

public class OpenTextFileIntoJTextArea  
{  
public static void main(String[]args)  
{  
 try  
 {  

  FileReader readTextFile=new FileReader("C:\\Hello.py");  

  Scanner fileReaderScan=new Scanner(readTextFile);  

  String storeAllString="";  

  while(fileReaderScan.hasNextLine())  
  {  
   String temp=fileReaderScan.nextLine()+"\n";  

   storeAllString=storeAllString+temp;  
  }  
  JTextArea textArea=new JTextArea(storeAllString);  
  textArea.setLineWrap(true);  
  textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);  
  JScrollPane scrollBarForTextArea=new JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);  
  JFrame frame=new JFrame("Open text file into JTextArea");  
  frame.add(scrollBarForTextArea);  
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
  frame.setSize(500,500);  
  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
  frame.setVisible(true);  
 }  
 catch(Exception exception)  
 {  

  System.out.println("Error in file processing");  
 }  
}  
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074428/how-can-i-set-each-character-to-a-different-color-background-color-in-a-jtextpan/13076649#13076649) example and its [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481698/highlighting-few-of-the-words-of-a-text-file-opened-in-a-frame/12482171#12482171). Also have a read on [Concurrency in Siwng](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and dont call `setSize` on `JFrame` use an appropriate `LayoutManager` and/or override `getPreferredSize()` and call `pack()` on `JFrame` before setting it visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with methods of JTextArea:

1. see the `getLineStartOffset(...)` and `getLineEndOffset(...)` methods.
2. then you can use the `getText(...)` method to get all the text for the line.
3. then you can use `String.indexOf(...)` to search the text for the location of "first".
4. now you can add the offset from the start of the line and the indexOf  methods to get the location of the text you want to highlight in the document
5. then you can use the `getHighlighter()` method of the text area to get the highlighter
6. finally you can use the `addHighlight()` method to highlight the word

Comment: Am new to Java can you show me an example by using codes that you describe in the steps. Thanks

Comment: I would start by creating a method like `highlightText(textArea, row, text)`. Then in the method you try to implement the code one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried playing around with :

JTextComponent.setSelectionStart(int), 
JTextComponent.setSelectionEnd(int), 
JTextComponent.setSelectedTextColor(java.awt.Color)