# How to search for certain words in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, textarea, jtextarea

I am trying to make an 'advanced text editor' in Java. However, I can't really find a way to search for certain words in a TextArea and set the font/color of only the word or words it finds. (Kind of like how Eclipse has a pinkish color for 'import', but blue for variable names.

Here is the source of what I have so far:
http://pastebin.com/1fKBUCWY

Comment: What you're looking can't be done, completely.  What you can do is cheat.  Take a look at [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437865/java-scroll-to-specific-text-inside-jtextarea/13438455#13438455) example.  It basically selects the text as it matches each occurance.  If you want highlighting, you'll need to look towards using a `JTextPane`, which can be accomplished in a similar manner to [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448558/highlight-a-word-in-jeditorpane/13449000#13449000)

Comment: textarea.getText().indexOf("thestring")??

Comment: @fmodos Now get the next match ;)

Comment: Or even [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727548/java-change-the-document-in-documentlistener/14727657#14727657)

Comment: @MadProgrammer `string.substring(idxMatch1+"searched".length()).indexOf('...')` lol... I missed the plural in the 'word' :/

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229611/code-completion-and-syntax-highlighting-in-swing/14230233#14230233) similar answer. Baically shows multiple examples which together would make code completion and syntax highlighting app. Specifically though to highlight letter(s) see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074428/how-can-i-set-each-character-to-a-different-color-background-color-in-a-jtextpan/13076649#13076649) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12482171/1133011) depending on which you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

First set up a listener on the TextArea that listens for the Space character. Store the word (between last event and this event) in a local variable and compare it with your special-words-list.

Responses to text-area event handling can be found at [Text Changed event in JTextArea? How to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740465/text-changed-event-in-jtextarea-how-to)

Hope this helps!